# < in Ant contrib propertyregex

Tags: regex, ant, ant-contrib

I want to replace `<` in a property value.

```
<propertyregex property="db.exec.schema.key" input="${db.exec.schema.key}" regexp="<" replace="/" global="true" />
```

causes *The value of attribute "regexp" associated with an element type "propertyregex" must not contain the '<' character*

Same when I escape it with a backslash, when I try `&lt;`, it does not match.

Any idea how to replace `<` with Ant?

Comment: Try inside a character class `[&lt;]`. Also, try a hex representation `\u003E` (or `\\u003E`).

Comment: Oops, apologies @WiktorStribiżew , the problem was not in the regexp itself but in using the same ant property as both source and destination. The property is not overwritten.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because It was a problem using ant, not the regexp task.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `&lt;` to escape the `<`. Same for other entity references:

```
>   &gt;
"   &quot;
&   &amp;
'   &apos;
```

Comment: Thank. Actually the problem was not in the regexp itself but in using the same ant property as both source and destination. The property is not overwritten. Works fine with & lt;